# Unable to access certain Samba shared folders from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, samba

I installed Samba and shared some folders to allow access from my Windows 7.
But currently I'm having some issues.

In my *smb.conf*

```
[MYFOLDER]
path = /usr/bin/MYFOLDER
read only = no
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes

[MYVIDEOS]
path = /usr/bin/MYVIDEOS
read only = no
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
```

For [MYFOLDER], I'm able to access from Windows. But I can't write to it.
For [MYVIDEOS], I can't even access it. Access is denied.

I need to be able to write and access both folders.  Anyone knows whats wrong?

Comment: Under what user does your samba deamon run? That user has to have access to the folders you are sharing.

Comment: problem solved after turning off selinux =)